# List of questions to be migrated to here once we get out of beta.

Tags: discussion, migration

Although it's very rare than we can mass migrate questions, there are some relevant questions lying around on other stack exchanges...

**Questions that fit less on the original site and more on our site:**

- [Looking for free/low cost music production software](https://superuser.com/questions/4162/looking-for-free-low-cost-music-production-software)
- [Combine Multiple Audio Files into a single higher-quality audio File](https://superuser.com/questions/40931/combine-multiple-audio-files-into-a-single-higher-quality-audio-file)
- [Removing noise from a recording](https://superuser.com/questions/24/remove-noise-from-a-recording)
- [Record a song (audio)](https://superuser.com/questions/188968/record-a-song-audio)
- [Finale: How do I add note to an existing chord using the simple entry tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/192152/finale-how-do-i-add-note-to-an-existing-chord-using-the-simple-entry-tool)
- ...

**Tags that might contain more questions that fit on our site:**

- [Super User - Audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- ...

Please add questions to this post so that we can more easily migrate when the time is ready.